# (Oracle SQL) how to add .00

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an integer, for example 3. Now I want to have them changed to 3.00, which function should I use?

I can only round 3.00 to 3, but don't know how to do it in reverse.

Comment: An integer doesn't have a decimal component, and numbers don't have any intrinsic format. So you're trying to format your numbers for display, to  always have two digits after the decimal point, correct?

Comment: @Alex Poole, yeah, thats right

Answer (score 2):

Numbers don't have any intrinsic format (though they may be constrained to a certain precision and scale), and it's up to your client how it displays a number. To display a number in a specific format you can convert it to a formatted string with [the `TO_CHAR` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130):

```
select to_char(3, '999990D00') from dual;

TO_CHAR(3,
----------
      3.00
```

The number format elements [are listed in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) too.

Here I've ended the format model with `D00` which gives you the decimal separator (which is affected by your NLS settings) followed by two digits - not always actually zeros, but that means a zero will still be shown if there is no significant digit in that position. I've also put a `0` before the decimal separator so that a number less than zero will still show that; so .3 will display as `0.30` for example.

For the rest of the model before that zero I've used `9`, so you won't see leading zeros. But you need enough placeholders in the model to allow for the longest value you expect to have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TO_CHAR` function

```
SELECT to_char(integerfield, '999990D00') 
FROM yourtable;
```

Or you can use

```
SELECT to_char(intfield, '9999.99') 
FROM yourtable;
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81a4b/5/0

Answer (score 0):

NUMBER doesn't have any format. What you see on the screen is for display so that you could easily interpret.

You need to either:

- set the numformat properly
- use TO_CHAR on the number with required format.

In **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> set numformat 9999D99
SQL> SELECT TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(3,'9999D99')) num FROM dual;

     NUM
--------
    3.00

SQL>
```